# Can I modify Geode's default logging behavior?

Tags: log4j2, gemfire, geode

Geode's out-of-the-box logging behavior does not include the "name" of the logger on each line (usually the name of the class invoking the Log4j `Logger`). I want to add this field to the default logger configuration, the one that logs to `<member-name>/<member-name>.log`.

Using the [instructions from the documentation](https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/99/geode/managing/logging/configuring_log4j2.html), I was able to successfully configure an *additional* logger using the configuration below -- it writes to a separate file from the default (`logs/app.log` in this case), but the default configuration *also* still logs as normal to the default file.

My expectation would be that providing my own `log4j2.xml` would *override* the default configuration, not supplement it. Is there anything I can do to override the behavior of that default logger?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="FATAL" shutdownHook="disable" packages="org.apache.geode.internal.logging.log4j">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="geode-pattern">[%level{lowerCase=true} %date{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z} &lt;%thread&gt; tid=%tid] - %c - %message%n%throwable%n</Property>
        <Property name="geode-default">true</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <File name="MyFile" fileName="logs/app.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${geode-pattern}"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="MyFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your configuration, actually I just tried it locally and the members only log to the configured file instead of the default:

```
$> gfsh start locator --name=locator1 --J=-Dlog4j.configurationFile=$CURRENT_DIRECTORY/log4j-custom.xml
$> gfsh -e "connect" -e "start server --name=server1 --J=-Dlog4j.configurationFile=$CURRENT_DIRECTORY/log4j-custom.xml"

$> gfsh -e "connect" -e "shutdown --include-locators=true"

$> tree -L 3
.
├── gfsh-0_0.log
├── locator1
│   ├── ConfigDiskDir_locator1
│   │   ├── BACKUPcluster_config.if
│   │   ├── BACKUPcluster_config_1.crf
│   │   ├── BACKUPcluster_config_1.drf
│   │   └── DRLK_IFcluster_config.lk
│   ├── GemFire_user
│   │   └── services
│   ├── locator10334view.dat
│   ├── locator10334views.log
│   ├── logs
│   │   └── app.log
│   └── vf.gf.locator.pid
├── log4j-custom.xml
└── server1
    ├── logs
    │   └── app.log
    └── vf.gf.server.pid
```

I've tried with the latest release, `GemFire 9.9.1`, maybe you're using an older version?, can you try with the latest one?.

Comment: Yes that's exactly my issue, thanks Juan. My organization has been stuck on Geode 1.6.0 (Gemfire 9.5) for a few years now . Everything works perfectly when I run my case in 1.11.0... I think it's time to push for an upgrade. Thanks for your time, your answers are always great!